# UITableView on iPad using Storyboards not loading cells

Tags: uitableview, core-data, ios7, uisplitviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a UItableView, using a UIStoryboard, with Core Data. On iPhone, the UITableView loads properly but it doesn't on iPad.

The tableViewController updates the navBar title and sets the toolbarItems properly, so pretty sure the storyboard file is being loaded as normal. When the TVC loads, I'm printing out the number of items that should be populating the table (correct value), but numberOfRowsInSection shows no items.

Inside the TVC, there are no device-centric code paths.The delegate and dataSource in the storyboard is hooked up, the Storyboard ID is set, so is the TV subclass.

I'm at a total loss here. If there's particular code I should post, let me know in comments.

```
AppsListTableViewController *appsList = (AppsListTableViewController *)[self appListTableViewController];
        UINavigationController * masterNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:appsList];
        masterNavController.toolbarHidden = NO;
        masterNavController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

        if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            BugsForAppDetailTableViewController *bugsForApp = (BugsForAppDetailTableViewController *)[self bugsForAppTVC];

            [appsList setDetailViewController:bugsForApp];

            UINavigationController * detailNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:bugsForApp];
            detailNavController.toolbarHidden = NO;
            detailNavController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

            [self.splitViewController setViewControllers:@[masterNavController, detailNavController]];
            self.splitViewController.delegate = appsList;    
        }

        else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            [_drawerController setCenterViewController:masterNavController];

            [_drawerController closeDrawerAnimated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                if (finished) {

                }
            }];
        }
```

And the bugsForAppTVC getter

```
- (BugsForAppDetailTableViewController *)bugsForAppTVC {
    if (_bugsForAppTVC == nil) {

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = nil;
        if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
        }   else {
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        }

        BugsForAppDetailTableViewController * centerViewController = (BugsForAppDetailTableViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BugsForAppDetailTableViewController_ID"];
        [centerViewController setMOContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];


        _bugsForAppTVC = centerViewController;
    }

    return _bugsForAppTVC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare your iPhone storyboard settings regarding the table view controller with those of the iPad storyboard. Check these items:

- `delegate` set
- `datasource` set
- Datasource delivers expected Core Data objects
- Controller subclass set correctly
- Cell subclass set correctly
- Cell identifiers correct
- Table view `IBOutlet` correctly defined if necessary

Comment: Thank for the reply @mundi, did the above, no affect. What else can I do? The data source does deliver the objects, but the tableView won't display them on iPad. iPhone works properly.

Comment: Update. I tried to use a standard UITableViewCell, thinking there was an issue with the tableViewCell subclass. Still nothing. It's as if the TableView refuses to populate.

Comment: It must be your iPad storyboard. Try to compare everything with the iPhone version, including font colours etc.

Comment: Went through that but it didn't work. I tried deleting the iPad VC from the storyboard and copying the iPhone version, that didn't work either. I then recreated the entire TVC scene in the iPad storyboard. Nothing. Could I have a corrupted storyboard file?

Comment: If you make it downloadable, I can take a look.

Comment: I've narrowed it down, I think.. I'm using a splitViewController and switching out view controllers as needed. The Q is updated.